# Как записать html-теги в файл?

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема, при записи html-тегов в файл)

```
string myHtml = "<html><head><title></title><style>body { width:130px; height: 30px;}</style></head><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>";
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("my.html");
    sw.Write(myHtml, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
    sw.Close();
```

Ругается "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

В чем дело?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `StreamWriter.Write(string, object)` форматирует входную строку, например `Write("Это {0} строка", "html")` запишет в файл `Это html строка`.

Правильно указывать кодировку в конструкторе StreamWriter:

```
string myHtml = "<html><head><title></title><style>body { width:130px; height: 30px;}</style></head><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("my.html", false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding ("windows-1251"));
sw.Write(myHtml);
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Да, я местами перепутал))) Надо было писать строкой выше)

Answer (score 0):

Ругается на фигурные скобки при преобразовании кодировки. Если убрать кодировку в записи - все ок. Да, у меня сохранил в 1251, но это частный случай имха.

Comment: А какую кодировку использовать? Не подскажите? А то с кириллицей проблемы...

Comment: Я всеми руками за юникод конечно) А так Tolyandre конечно же правильно сказал насчет конструктора - моя невнимательность ;)